# Flutter - How to use SQFLite package as local storage for Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have an existing flutter mobile application, which I want to convert into flutter web application. I used SQFlite as a local storage DB in mobile app, how can I use that for web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, the web does not support sqlite in any acceptable ways (yes there are in memory solution but no 
persistency, see https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/212).

Since there is no decent solution on the web, as of today, support is not planned.

IndexedDB or any solution on top of it should be considered for storage on the Web.

Comment: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/idb_sqflite#-example-tab- @alextk wat about this package??

Comment: This is actually the opposite of providing sqflite for the web. It does provide the indexedDB (web) API on top of sqflite (mobile). See example here: https://github.com/alextekartik/flutter_app_example/tree/master/notepad of an application using indexedDB on flutter web and idb_sqflite on mobile. The main drawback of indexedDB is that it is not very 'dartish', i.e. most argument are dynamic making it harder to enforce strong mode. However it allows to have the same database code for mobile and web.